# Is it ok to remove possible duplicate box after reopening?

Tags: support

Closed and reopened questions for reasons of being exact duplicates continue to carry the "possible duplicate" box. Is it polite to edit the question and remove the box. I fear I might not get answers as people might assume duplication?

Comment: [Now these links are automatically removed when a duplicate question is reopened.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101708/dont-automatically-edit-the-post-to-insert-possible-duplicate-links)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please remove the box; in fact, it's confusing as it is, since you also have the original statement of the problem in a box.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Arturo that the box should be removed. I would add: If there aren't too many comments under the question, then it might be helpful to add a comment explaining why the question is *not* a duplicate of that other question. Alternatively, there are cases where it's good to add that piece of information to the question.